# How to Match Multi-Digit Regex In Javascript Using the Star

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract a multi-digit number which is preceeded by a non-digit from a string in javascript, but having trouble. For example, I want to get the "32" out of "B32 is the floor".

```
var str = "B23 is the floor."
var num = str.match(/\d*/);
$("#result").append(Object.prototype.toString.call(num) + ', ');
$("#result").append(Object.prototype.toString.call(num[0]) + ', ');
$("#result").append(num[0] + ', ');
$("#result").append(num[0].length);
```

Returns:

```
Result:[object Array], [object String], , 0
```

num[0] seems to be an empty string.

For some reason the regext /\d*/ does not work the way it is supposed to. I have tried /(\d)*/, /(\d)*/, /[0-9]*/, and some other reasonable and unreasonable things, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Here is my jsFiddle if you want to take a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/PLYHF/3/

Comment: Try `/[a-zA-Z]+(\d+)/`

Comment: `/[^\d]+(\d+)/` is an alternative.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PLYHF/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the regex parser is "lazy". It sees that your regex is perfectly fine with "nothing" (since `*` means 0 or more), so anything will pass.

Instead, try `/\d+/`. This will force there to be at least one digit.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is match for /^0-9/, and then get the second value (`Array[1]`) from the returned array. That will contain what's captured by the first group. It would end up looking like this:

```
var str = "B23 is the floor."
var num = str.match(/[^0-9\s]([0-9]+)/);
$('#result').append(num[1]);
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PLYHF/4/)

Comment: `/^0-9/` catches *space* witch means `123` from "Random number 123." will end up in `#result`.

Comment: Fixed it by adding a `\s` to the range

Answer (score 0):

```
parseInt(/[A-Z]+([0-9]+)/.exec('B23 is the floor.')[1]); // 23
```